# WSO2 API Manager Version 4.2.0 endpoints directory not found

Tags: wso2, endpoint

We have migrated from API Manager 3.2 to 4.2. Now, I cannot find the directory "repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\endpoints" where I would expect the API endpoint configuration as it was before. The documentation still describes this directory as the point these XMLs are stored and can be configured.
Does anybody knows where this information is stored now? Database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's in the DB now, if you want to maintain a list of Endpoints in the filesystem you will have to whitelist them. To do this add the following to your `deployment.toml` then create the endpoint directory and add the files.

```ini
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
endpoints = ["endpoint1.xml", "endpoint2.xml"]
```